# Nodemailer is not sending mails to valid emailids if array contains invalid emailids

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have tried to send multiple emails with nodemailer-smtp-transport in nodejs but if multiple recipients list contains valid and invalid email ids then mails are not going to valid emails ,always it is going to error callback.

My sample code:-

```
var testemails=["name.@gmail.com,santosh@gmail.com"];
var mailOptions = {     
    from:config.email_from_addr,        
    //bcc :receiver_email,
    bcc:testemails,
    subject :subject,
    html:html
};      
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host:config.email_host_name,
    port: 25
}));
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){    
    console.log("error: "+error);
    console.log("info: "+info);
    if(error){
        //console.log("Rejected: "+info.rejected);
        console.log("error",'Failed to send: '+subject+' ; Error: '+error);         
        return callback(null);
    }else{
        console.log("info","Promotion_EmailFurnished:  "+subject+" : "+receiver_email); 
        return callback(null);
    }
});
```

//**here Invalid emaild: name.@gmail.com and
 valid emailId:  santosh@gmail.com**
and how to  collect if mails are failed to send due to invalid emails?

Any help?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Have you tried sending it one-by-one, such as by using `testemails.forEach(addr => {...})`?

Comment: Hello ionizer,Ya i have tried ,it is failing to invalid email and sending to valid ids but I dont want again iterate to array so

Answer (score 0):

Your array is wrong,

```
var testemails=["name.@gmail.com,santosh@gmail.com"];
```

Should be,

```
var testemails=["name.@gmail.com","santosh@gmail.com"];
```

**Update**

Above is just the first thing wrong with you code,

***Second***

in mailOptions you forgot to put the to address, bcc might work for nodemailer but without a to address it will fail from smtp endpoint.

```
var mailOptions = {     
    from:config.email_from_addr,        
    to : testemails,
    bcc:testemails,
    subject :subject,
    html:html
};
```

***Third***,

Where is the password field for the transporter ?

sample for latest node mailer :

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    host: "smtp.gmail.com", // hostname
    secureConnection: true, // use SSL
    port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
    auth: {
        user: "gmail.user@gmail.com",
        pass: "userpass"
    }
});
```

Please use this for more info as well : [Docs](https://nodemailer.com)

Comment: If i tried with this array also var testemails=["name.@gmail.com","santosh@gmail.com"]; ,it is still getting fail.I think it is not issue with array.

Comment: Thank you Kalana Demel.I have tried by correcting first and second points what you mentioned still no luck and one more thing is it necessary to  add auth: {
        user: "gmail.user@gmail.com",
        pass: "userpass"
    } field?

Comment: yes, but depends on who your smtp provider is, they usually give a user name and pass word, if it's google above should work with less secure apps enabled.

Comment: But we didnt get username and password.So we have tried nodemailer-smtp-tranport module ,we have tested without passing auth filed with valid receipients ,its worked.I think it is not an issue if we dont pass it.

Comment: Who's the smtp provider ?

Comment: Yes we using postfix by enabling with Amazon SES.

Comment: Usually it have password a as well. check /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd in your smtp server to check, if your server hasn't been configred with auth above should work as well, what's the error you're getting atm.

Comment: Yes I will check it and currently I am getting this  Error: Invalid recipient "khavekarsantosh91.@gmail.com"

Comment: That's because this email is not valid, you cannot have a mail address with '.' before '@' , https://tools.verifyemailaddress.io/

Comment: Ya  its correct but usually it should failed to only invalid email ids right ,but here entire array of emailids getting fail ,atleast mail should go to other emailids

Comment: depends on how node mailer handles the error, which I'm not familiar with on this particular scenario, but did it work if all email address's were correct ?

Comment: So probably nodemailer must be validating first and throwing an error if even one is incorrect, it's not something you can control on your end, so better make sure all are valid emails before sending the mail.

Comment: Yes you are correct.I have check each email id is valid or not if it valid then only i have to push in an array to process.